# Status from wire: INVALID_KEY status: null Google drive

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am creating a Google Drive Integration in my existing app.

I have followed Google Drive Integration instructions.

I have created Oauth 2.0 client key for android using sha1 and package name.

I am just using code from below link for testing purpose but I can't make it run.

[Tutorial](https://github.com/alberovalley/Google-Drive-Tutorial)

But each time I try upload file I am getting below exception.

```
02-25 18:18:40.703: W/GLSActivity(1853): [anc] Status from wire: INVALID_KEY status: null
02-25 18:18:40.703: W/GLSActivity(1853): [anc] Status from wire: INVALID_KEY status: null
02-25 18:18:40.703: I/GLSUser(1853): GLS error: INVALID_KEY skypatel7@gmail.com oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
02-25 18:18:40.710: W/GLSActivity(1853): [anc] Status from wire: Unknown status: UNKNOWN
02-25 18:18:40.710: W/System.err(24843): com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException
02-25 18:18:40.718: W/System.err(24843):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:224)
02-25 18:18:40.718: W/System.err(24843):    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859)
02-25 18:18:40.718: W/System.err(24843):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeUploadInitiation(MediaHttpUploader.java:352)
02-25 18:18:40.718: W/System.err(24843):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:266)
02-25 18:18:40.718: W/System.err(24843):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:408)
02-25 18:18:40.718: W/System.err(24843):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:328)
02-25 18:18:40.718: W/System.err(24843):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:449)
02-25 18:18:40.718: W/System.err(24843):    at com.skyproductivity.android.trackerdrive.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:116)
02-25 18:18:40.718: W/System.err(24843):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
02-25 18:18:40.718: W/System.err(24843): Caused by: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown
02-25 18:18:40.726: W/System.err(24843):    at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
02-25 18:18:40.726: W/System.err(24843):    at com.google.android.gms.Auth. GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
02-25 18:18:40.726: W/System.err(24843):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:192)
02-25 18:18:40.726: W/System.err(24843):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:217)
02-25 18:18:40.726: W/System.err(24843):    ... 8 more
```

`

I have already spent more then 50 Hr searching this very error.

Comment: Did you solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i drop idea of using google google drive api using google pay service.

I use java Api client for google drive.

In this method you need to use webview for authentication. refere below tutorial.

http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/01/android-google-oauth2.html

Answer (score 0):

I had this, I did everything right but still failed. Finally I created a new 
Project in Google Developers Console. In there I created everything again.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post. I am not sure you have got the answer or not. But here is my solution:
This error is most probably due to the fact that there is some error in your Client Id for Android. 
On Android, a combination of the Android package name, and the SHA-1 fingerprint of the signing key is used to retrieve profile.
There are following two solutions:
1) Check for any typo in package name.
2) There can be multiple Android keystore on your system and the key which was used to sign the APK might be different than the one you put in developers console. 
For ex: On Ubuntu, when you call

`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v`

There are two locations: /root/.android and /home/ubuntu/.android. Check for the SHA1 key one was used to sign the apk.

Thanks. I hope this helps.

Arpit